# How to add content to Polymer SPA example

Tags: polymer, single-page-application

regarding to that article https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/spa.html i want to know how to add some content? 

i know there is an example which loads external html files. but how to add my own content in the other examples?

Thank you

kind regards
Viktoria

Answer (score 0):

on the page you linked there is a section headed "then drop in your content:"

then it is followed with this code.

```
 <div layout horizontal center-center fit>
  <core-animated-pages  selected="0" transitions="slide-from-right">
    <section layout vertical center-center>
      <div>Single</div>
    </section>
    <section layout vertical center-center>
      <div>page</div>
    </section>
    ...
  </core-animated-pages>
</div>
```

in that code each section tag is a diff page and the content of that page is in the enclosed div tag `<div>Single</div>` replace that tag to change the app content. it might also help to look over the documentation on the elements used in that example so you have a better understanding of how they work.

animated pages
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-animated-pages.html