# Polymer single page application with lightbox

Tags: polymer, lightbox, single-page-application

regarding to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914357/how-to-add-content-to-polymer-spa-example)** question i have changed my polymer spa a little to load content dynamically.
next thing is to add a lightbox gallery. 
i have found a very lightweigt version **[here](https://github.com/felixhagspiel/jsOnlyLightbox)**
as standalone it works very good but in my dynamic content page i am not able to get this work. 
i created a git repo **[here](https://github.com/LadyViktoria/PolymerSPA)**

Thanks a lot.
Viktoria

ps: next things are a contact form some nice effect like wow.js, language selector and icon fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only planing to put static content like a custom element on a page then I do not see the need in using a array of content. so i would change your final.html

```
     <div layout horizontal center-center fit>
      <core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{route}}" valueattr="hash"
                           transitions="slide-from-right">
          <section hash="about" layout vertical center-center>
            <about-us></about-us>
          </section>
      </core-animated-pages>
    </div>
```

then you have 1 page that you can access with http://address.com/#about

to add another page all you need to do is add another `<section>` with with a hash attribute of what ever you want the route to be.

i am going to assume that the tutorial you are working through uses a auto-binding template and in javascript has waited for that template to be bound. or that you are working inside a custom element.

to set the default route you would change the route line in your javascript to something like

```
this.route = this.route || 'Single';
```

change `'Single'` to what ever you want the default page to be.

hope that helps.

note i also removed the on-tap function as i only see that being useful for that demo.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you :-)
i have found a solution with the dynamic content. it works good. just finished a contact form. it is only the lightbox that will not work. i tested if scripts were load with a simple js alert in a dynamic content page and it works. maybe it is the lightbox. i will test other lightboxes tomorrow.
i have uploaded all my changes into the git repo above.
kind regards
Viktoria